# Grails compile error java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException where upgrading from 2.0.1 to 2.0.2

Tags: grails, compilation

I have a production grails application that uses release 1.3.7.  I want to bring it up to date and use grails 2.2.0.  I did a 'grails upgrade' directly to 2.2.0 and received a strange compile error.  I then attempted incremental upgrades from 1.3.7 to 2.0.1 and was able to get my application to compile.  When I upgrade to 2.0.2, I see the same strange compile error that I saw with the direct upgrade to 2.2.0.  The problem with the compile error is it doesn't reference any of my software, just components of grails and java.  Here is the compile error:

]# grails compile

| Compiling 159 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
General error during canonicalization: String index out of range: 1

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
        at grails.util.GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyNameRepresentation(GrailsNameUtils.java:224)
        at grails.util.GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyName(GrailsNameUtils.java:183)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DefaultASTDatabindingHelper.getPropertyNamesToIncludeInWhiteList(DefaultASTDatabindingHelper.java:201)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DefaultASTDatabindingHelper.addDefaultDatabindingWhitelistField(DefaultASTDatabindingHelper.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DefaultASTDatabindingHelper.injectDatabindingCode(DefaultASTDatabindingHelper.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.web.ControllerDomainTransformer.performInjection(ControllerDomainTransformer.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.injection.GrailsAwareInjectionOperation.call(GrailsAwareInjectionOperation.java:140)
        at  org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:967)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:546)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:524)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:501)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:480)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:216)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:909)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Grailsc.compile(Grailsc.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:607)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:260)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:220)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:170)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compile(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:266)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compile$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compile(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:237)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compile.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy:69)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:992)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1112)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1006)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:279)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:914)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1093)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1049)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:697)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
        at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1112)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1006)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
        at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:992)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:697)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1112)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1006)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
        at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:699)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:693)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:432)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:383)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:362)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:228)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)

1 error

I've read the 2.0.2 release note: http://beta.grails.org/2.0.2+Release+Notes, but nothing seems to help point me to a place to begin to find my problem.

Comment: Can you trim that error message down and format it correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. It's a bit of a whopper for folks to digest. Thanks.

Comment: My 2 cents (in general terms): when you upgrade a framework, it is really OK to go step by step. But I think it would be better to try and upgrade to the latest maintenance version (in this case 2.0.4) instead of every single maintenance version (2.0.1, 2.0.2, etc..). Said that, try grails clean before compiling and if you still get the error, please attach (and format) also the code that seems to generate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you by any chance have a method in one of your domain classes named simply: `set()`, with one argument?  The error seems to originate from [code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/DefaultASTDatabindingHelper.java#L201) that builds a list of properties eligible for binding by checking for the presence of setters.

Comment: Andrew, wow you nailed.  That is exactly the situation I had, I repaired it and the application will now compile with grails 2.0.2.  Did you just backtrack that from the first piece of grails code listed in the trace?  I'd appreciate if you could discuss your logic a little.

Comment: No real logic, but yes, I worked down from the top or your stacktrace (ignoring internal/system functions).  As an aside, it looks like this behavior still exists in the latest version (2.2.1), and it seems like a bug, might be worth a JIRA ticket...

Comment: Thank you for this answer. How did you figure it out from the stacktrace??

Comment: @Aston: I suspect that was experience talking rather than a detailed reading of the stack trace...  In the one week that I've been using Grails, I've been bitten so many times by "magic" behaviour!

Comment: @MarkKCowan, I understand the frustration caused by unexpected and 'magic' behaviour. Unfortunately, in my experience, it is inevitable with any high level functionality frameworks. I had my fair share of frustration in the beginning, but in the long term Grails saves my a huge amount of time. Even though at times I need to look at the source code for answers.

Comment: @Aston:  Thankfully I've finished that Grails project now and I'm back on Node.js...   I don't mind having to type one short line of code to make something happen, with the benefit being that I can see what my program does by reading the code instead of having to dig through framework and parser sources.